# Run MPI jobs on two nodes

Tags: mpi

I want to run an MPI job using mpirun on two nodes such that 20 MPI processes should run on one node and 18 MPI processes should run on second node. I am using a 2 nodes with 24 cores.There are 12 physical cores and 12 virtual cores due to hyperthreading.

Comment: *I want to ...* doesn't express a question.  You'll have to provide a lot more information about your set-up and be clearer about what you want assistance with, to have any hope of useful help.

Comment: Which MPI library are you using ?

Comment: Hi Gilles - I am using openmpi/3.0.0

Comment: Then you can `mpirun --host host1:20,host2:18 a.out`

Comment: Hi Giles - I am trying an MPI job for Graph500. I am allowed 4 nodes at most. Each node has 12 cores and 12 virtual cores in addition due to hyperthreading (24 cores in total). On a single node, I was able to run using 15, 16, 17 till 24 MPI processes (or cores). I also was able to run 48 MPI processes for 2 nodes and 96 MPI processes for 4 nodes, but I am not able to run 38 MPI processes using 2 nodes or 60 processes using 3 nodes. The job runs successfully using all cores but not less. I am using: #!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -n 38 => cores
#SBATCH -N 1 => nodes
mpirun -np 29 ./executable